# HttpClient responding errorcode 415

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

Im building an console application that should post data to an WebApi, i tested the Api using Postman and through that it is working. Now i am building the C# code in the console application but i can't get it to work because it always returns Http error code 415.

My Postman config:
[image]
Please dont mind the error 400, because that is because my DateTime isn't formatted well. With the correct formatting everything succeeds.

This is my code for posting to the WebApi:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52277/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", LoginResponse.access_token);
                StringContent parameterContent = new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("pssltl=0000000015340882"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/PutData", parameterContent);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

//EDIT
My API controller:

```
//POST api/PutData
        [Route("PutData")]
        [HttpPost]
        //Authorize nodig voor deze handeling
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult PutData(TijdRegistratieModel trm)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (trm == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Geen data ingestuurd!");
            }
            _repo.InsertTijdregistratie(trm.pssltl, trm.Start);
            return Ok(trm);
        }
```

TijdsRegistratieModel:

```
public class TijdRegistratieModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string pssltl { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct `MediaType` header ?

Comment: Yes i do, if i post any other MediaType header with Postman i get an 415 as well, so x-www-form-urlencoded should be good

Comment: post the controller code. That media type is mostly used when using HTML form submission

Comment: added, but this mediatype works fine when i am requesting an access token from the server though

Comment: did you try `application/json`/